# yii make a join with CDbCriteria

Tags: join, yii

I've to retrieve a model with his related.
For example, i've a table game and an other one bet. 
bet has a column with a game_id

For now, i retrieve only the game model, not the related bet. i try too a left join without success
Here is what i did

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->select = '*';
            $criteria->alias = 'Game';
            $criteria->join='INNER JOIN bet ON Game.id=bet.game_id';
            //$criteria->condition='bet.user_id='.$_userId.' or user_id is null';
            $criteria->order = 'date_game ASC';
            return $this->model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: exactly what you want to retrieve please elaborate

Comment: if you want to achieve one game `Game::model()->findByPk(id)` is all you need (that is without the related model)

Comment: I'd like to have my game with related bet for a user. So i did simply a join between both but i receive only the game model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model return only attributes have on model .If you want extend the related table you need to use **with**

**in your model**

```
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
             'benmodel'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Ben', 'game_id'=>'id');

            );
   }
```

**in your controller**

```
        return $this->model()->with('benmodel')->findAll();  //you get both table columns
```

Comment: thanks for you proposition, i think i've an issue with my relation()
here is what i've tried: 'bets' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Bet','game_id'=>'id'), but have an exception => It must specify the relation type, the related active record class and the foreign key

Comment: change order of this 'game_id'=>'id' into 'id'=>'game_id'

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your model and db fields and their types. You are try to insert array into table. That'y you get this. There is no validation problem now. Because it was swiched off by my code

Comment: Do u want user data's with ben table colums or opposite

Comment: You can try alternatively by pure sql query.

Answer (score 1):

i modify relation in game controller

```
'bet' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Bet', 'game_id'),
```

Now i can have the game with related bet by user.

```
return $this->model()->with(array('bet'=>array('condition'=>'user_id='.$_userId.' or user_id is null')))->findAll($criteria);
```